# swift UNUserNotificationCenter with function

Tags: ios, push-notification, swift3

I am using `UNUserNotificationCenter` for my app development.

I would like to apply a function to the `UNUserNotificationCenter` just before the `UNUserNotificationCenter` is turned on and the data obtained from that function.

I think it is inaccurate and inaccurate to compare the time I set for an alarm with a timer every fixed time.

What method should be used to get a function to run at a certain time?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you could do something like this: [Swift - using timers/system clock/background threads to do something in my application every hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915137/swift-using-timers-system-clock-background-threads-to-do-something-in-my-appli)
Just using UNUserNotificationCenter instead. You should be able to find more instructions here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194

Good luck!